# Is it necessary to transform the features before applying machine learning algorithm?

Tags: normal-distribution, data-transformation

I have a dataset which  contains features with skewed distribution and I want to feed it to a machine learning algorithm ( being general here). Do I need to always transform the features so that its more of a normal distribution? or is it ok to not to do so and guarantees a good estimate?

What are the advantages/disadvantages of doing so?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you're using linear models you should transform them, as this might yield better results.

However, more sophisticated ML algorithms don't require such transformations. One exception I'm aware of is to use PCA to transform the features in order to de-correlate them, if your dataset suffers from multicollinearity.

Comment: Apparently, there's a word called leptokurtophobia, which cracked me up. 
https://www.qualitydigest.com/inside/quality-insider-column/do-you-have-leptokurtophobia.html

Comment: Say what if we have have multi modal data? Should we still strive to achieve normality. In my opinion if the data is multi-modal it will cause more damage to transform it into a normal distribution.

Comment: I agree with you. I think that, when dealing with multi-modal data it would probably hurt your model because it would have to learn from a distribution much different than the actual one.